# Design object for availability product stock of partner store

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

Allowing a store whether a product is available in the stock of another store partner, the latter may either accept or reject the request, in all cases the applicant is informed of réponse.

I want to implement a diagram class.
Now I have a class product, and a class list of collections of products.
I don't know how to represent a class of operation "request for product availability.

Is there a design pattern corresponding to this situation?

or a simple example of class diagram would be welcome.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand.  Could you make an attempt to clarify the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are talking about representing your design in some suitable diagram, in which case you need to study some "Modeling Language" - probably the most widely used today being UML. This is a big topic, but you could start [here](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/umlClassDiagrams.pdf).

Now diagrams such as these are really only useful when your design reaches some level of complexity. Here you are thinking about just a couple of classes and one method a diagram won't help much. So maybe you are doing this as a learning exercise?

You probably need both a Class diagram and a [Sequence Diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm).

The major thing you seem to be confused about is how to represent Operations, they are just listed against the class. So your Store class would have an operation transferInventory().

So your class diagram is very simple only a couple of classes Store, Product. But the interesting thing is that your Sequence diagram will show that you have more than one instance of the Store class: StoreA, StoreB and the instances communicate with each other.

One thing you haven't talked about: how did StoreA **know** that StoreB exists? Why did it choose that Store to ask for a product. There's some additional classes here such as a registry of Stores. I would be much more interested in figuring out that than in drawing diagrams.